# Select * from Subquery VS Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Below are two statements, is it totally same?

(1)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DEPTNO, ROUND(AVG(SAL)) AS AVG_SAL 
     FROM EMP 
     GROUP BY DEPTNO 
     ORDER BY DEPTNO);
```

(2)

```
SELECT DEPTNO, ROUND(AVG(SAL)) AS AVG_SAL 
FROM EMP 
GROUP BY DEPTNO 
ORDER BY DEPTNO;
```

Comment: Does Oracle allow the first one? `ORDER BY DEPTNO` doesn't make any sense in  a derived table

Comment: It doesn't make sense, @Martin, but Oracle allows it.

Comment: @Littlefoot and does using it make any guarantees about the overall order of results from the outer query?

Comment: As you know, @Martin, it does not - the "final" ORDER BY is the only guarantee (the one that's missing in the 1st query). Basically, ORDER BY should be moved out of the subquery.

Comment: Unless you have a specific requirement that makes the first solution a must, you should keep things clear and not complicate your query for no reason. The subquery also add a layer of complexity if you need to troubleshoot your results.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that the queries will generate identical results (as the `ORDER BY` clause in the sub-query will not be changed by wrapping it in a view that does not apply any additional orderings); however, no, they are not identical if you compare the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s for the two queries:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DEPTNO, ROUND(AVG(SAL)) AS AVG_SAL 
      FROM EMP 
      GROUP BY DEPTNO 
      ORDER BY DEPTNO);

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                            |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 2533405727                                                  |
> |                                                                              |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    14 |   364 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  VIEW               |      |    14 |   364 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   SORT GROUP BY     |      |    14 |   364 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   364 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                              |
> | Note                                                                         |
> | -----                                                                        |
> |    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)                     |
> ```

and then:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT DEPTNO, ROUND(AVG(SAL)) AS AVG_SAL 
FROM EMP 
GROUP BY DEPTNO 
ORDER BY DEPTNO;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                           |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 15469362                                                   |
> |                                                                             |
> | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |    14 |   364 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |      |    14 |   364 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   364 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                             |
> | Note                                                                        |
> | -----                                                                       |
> |    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)                    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dbeac5d52c3e82d30d22c3db012ca0dc)*

---

There is an additional step in the explain plan for the first query to generate the view that is not optimised out by the SQL compiler.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, to get a *identical* statement you must add the *outer* `order by` clause to the statement **(1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DEPTNO, ROUND(AVG(SAL)) AS AVG_SAL 
     FROM EMP 
     GROUP BY DEPTNO 
     ORDER BY DEPTNO)
ORDER BY DEPTNO;
```

This will allow Oracle to eliminate the *subquery* and produce an identical *execution plan* as for the query **(2)**

```
-------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name | 
-------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |      |  
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY             |      |  
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| EMP  | 
-------------------------------------------
```

In your formulation you **can** expect the *same result* of both queries, but **you must** be prepared for *surprise*.